# How to integrate odoo with elastix

Tags: python, odoo, asterisk, elastix

I am trying to integrate **Odoo** with **Elastix** . so i downloads all the module from [https://github.com/OCA/connector-telephony](https://github.com/OCA/connector-telephonyt) . and install asterisk_click2dial, base_phone, crm_phone module , but i don't understand how this is configure , like AMI login and password, asterisk server name or if you installed this , you may be better know all the fields of telephony menu . i both the OS installed in virtual box also , if you have any idea please share with me .

Comment: What about reading the doc by [Akretion](http://www.akretion.com/open-source-contributions/openerp-asterisk-voip-connector)?

Comment: Thanx @CZoellner for reply , i don't understand **AMI(Asterisk Manager Interface)** and how to config it , becouse  i don't get any file like **etc/asterisk/manager.conf** .

Comment: Maybe Elastix is handling it anywhere else? It has to be somewhere.

Comment: Elastix is freepbx -based distro.

Answer (score 0):

AMI Manager login/password for elastix can be added in /etc/asterisk/manager_custom.conf

Most likly you should read more about AMI interface.

You question is too broad. First of all can recommend read entry-level book for asterisk (for example Asterisk The Future of Telephony), after that study doc for AMI(useless without asterisk understanding)

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4817239